# Controlysis - how to use Unreal Engine 4

Tags: unreal-engine4

Yesterday I bought this plugin [Controlysis](https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/controlysis#&gid=1&pid=1)
Documentation isn't helpful for me . Can anyone help me?
Anyone who know how to implement this?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Stefan! Here we are expecting clear, specific issues. Please see [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: I can't upload images...how cand I be more clear? :)

Comment: Please read the article I've linked. Describe the particular problem you've encountered and what have you tried to solve it.